# How to specify the character set when db2 command in Linux read an SQL file

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I use the following command to execute SQLs in a file by db2 command line processor (CLP) in Linux:

```
db2 -f script.sql
```

The encoding for script.sql is Windows-1252 (CP1252). When I run the command on server A, db2 reads and executes the file successfully but when I run the command on server B, db2 fails to read the file because it cannot recognize the French character encoded in Windows-1252.

The LANG environment variables on both servers are the same (en_GB). The versions of db2 CLP on both servers are the same and the operating systems are the same.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact error message that corresponds to "fails to read the file".   Behaviour variations can happen if the *database encoding* differs between servers, or if the system default LANG differs between the servers (as distinct from the value of LANG for your session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the corresponding environment variable in your session.

```
export DB2CODEPAGE=1252  
—- just in case if you ran db2 commands previously  
—- in this session  
db2 terminate  
—- if there is no connect command in the script  
db2 connect to mydb
db2 -f script.sql  

—- if you need other Db2 commands  
—- with your default code page in this session  
db2 connect reset  
db2 terminate  
unset DB2CODEPAGE
```